# Framer Motion not updating scrollYProgress

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm using [Framer Motion's `useViewportScroll`](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/motionvalue#useviewportscroll) hook to track the user's scroll on my page, but it isn't updating. I came across [this](https://cole.codes/posts/framer-motion-useviewportscroll-with-height-100-parallax-bug) article, which explains how Framer Motion uses `document.body.clientHeight` and `window.innerHeight` to calculate the viewport scroll.

The article explains how some CSS can break this, specifically if `document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight <= 0`.

I can't seem to figure out how this wouldn't be true. Even with no CSS at all in my react app, that expression evaluates to true. You can see it in [this example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clientheight-innerheight-example-e9w4b).

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the reason you're not seeing updates is not because of any css.
Framer seems to calculate it's state **standalone** from react. So when Framer updates its values internally. **react won't necessarily trigger a re-render** with the updated values. (probably this is done for performance).

You can hook into the state changes by subscribing to an `onChange` handler that Framer is exposing and set the state you're interested in.

For example, the `onChange` on `scrollYProgress` will call `setState`, triggering react to re-render.

```
import React from "react";
import { useViewportScroll } from "framer-motion"

const FramerPostionHook = () => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useViewportScroll();
  const [hookedYPostion, setHookedYPosition] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    // hook into the onChange, store the current value as state.
    scrollYProgress.onChange(v=> setHookedYPosition(v));
  },[scrollYProgress]); //make sure to re-subscriobe when scrollYProgress changes

  return  (<>
  scrollYProgress.current: {scrollYProgress.current}<br/>
  scrollYProgress.hookedYPostion: {hookedYPostion}<br/>
  </>)
}
```

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clientheight-innerheight-example-forked-33xwb?file=/src/App.js:0-534)

Comment: Amazing, this is what i was looking for!

Comment: I simply love you

Comment: I am having a similar problem but - would really love some help on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077656/how-can-i-get-framer-motion-3-3-0-scrollyprogress-to-work-in-react

Answer (score 10):

Note that now `onChange()` is deprecated and replaced with [`useMotionValueEvent()`](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-motion-value-event/).

An update to Lars' answer is below using `useMotionValueEvent()`

```js
import React from "react";
import { useMotionValueEvent, useScroll } from "framer-motion"

const FramerPostionHook = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["start end", "end end"],
  });
  const [hookedYPostion, setHookedYPosition] = React.useState(0);
  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, "change", (latest) => {
    setHookedYPosition(latest);
  })

  return  (<>
  scrollYProgress.current: {scrollYProgress.current}<br/>
  scrollYProgress.hookedYPostion: {hookedYPostion}<br/>
  </>)
}
```