# How can I get Framer Motion 3.3.0 scrollYprogress to work in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, framer-motion

Hi I cant get scrollYProgress to work (xLeft). If I console log it I get nothing. Where as scrollY works fine. I am on a project using an older version of framer (nothing I can do about that). I know someone else had a similar problem but I can figure out how to implement it. I am using Mui - if that has any relevance. Would love some help here.

```
export const TwelveTwelveAni: React.FC<TwelveTwelveAniProps> = (props) => {
  const { headerOne, headerTwo, registerRef } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  const { scrollY } = useViewportScroll();
  const { scrollYProgress } = useViewportScroll();

  scrollY.onChange((value) => console.log(value));
  scrollYProgress.onChange((value) => console.log(value));

  const xLeft = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [-1100, 1000]);
  const xRight = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 2500], [1000, -1100]);

  return (
    <Grid xs={12} md={12}>
      <Box className={classes.mainWrapperColCenter}>
        <motion.div style={{ x: xLeft }}>
          <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.jumbo}>
            {headerOne}
          </Typography>
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div style={{ x: xRight }}>
          <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.jumbo}>
            {headerTwo}
          </Typography>
        </motion.div>
      </Box>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code looks alright, i would advice you upgrade the framerMotion Library to the latest package, talk to the owner of the project and see if you can upgrade the package

the latest api for **scrollY** and **scrollYProgress** is **useScroll()**

what will i change from this code?

```
const {scrollY, scrollYProgress} = useScroll();

const xLeft = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [-1100, 1000]);

const xRight = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 2500], [1000, -1100]);

useEffect(() => {
    const removeA = scrollY.onChange((value) => console.log(value));
    const removeB = scrollYProgress.onChange((value) => console.log(value));

    return () => {
        removeA()
        removeB()
    }
})
```